# Docsy shortcode for tabs only working with html content and not markdown

Tags: markdown, documentation, hugo, hugo-shortcode, docsy

According to Docsy documentation [here](https://www.docsy.dev/docs/adding-content/shortcodes/#shortcode-details)

> If your content is markdown, use the percent sign % as outermost delimiter of your tab shortcode, your markup should look like {{% tab %}}Your **markdown** content{{% /tab %}}. In case of HTML content, use square brackets <> as outermost delimiters: {{< tab >}}Your **HTML** content{{< /tab >}}.

As my tab content has markdown code that I need rendered, I'm using % as delimiter. But is not working, as it is rendering me the content as code block, which I understand is the default unless otherwise specified.

I tried:

`{{% tabpane %}} {{% tab header="Tab 1 name" %}} markdown content for tab 1 {{% /tab %}} {{% tab header="tab 2 name" %}} Markdown content for tab 2 {{% /tab %}} {{% /tabpane %}}` 
And it did not work:
[Using % as delimiter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPHDt.png)

So I tried HTML delimiter to check if delimiter parameter functionality was working at all and *it kinda worked*:

`{{< tabpane >}} {{< tab header="Tab 1 name" >}} markdown content for tab 1 {{< /tab >}} {{< tab header="tab 2 name" >}} Markdown content for tab 2 {{< /tab >}} {{< /tabpane >}}`

[Using HML delimiter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9cyv.png)

It renders the content as HTML!
So the feature *seems* to be working, just not for markdown content.
This is my code:
[My code on VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l2c3.png)

I'm using VSC, and previewing changes on localhost with Hugo.
I would be really thankful if someone could help me figure out what is happening here, that is, what I'm doing wrong.
Thank you!

EDIT:

Specifying

`lang="markdown"`

in tabpane seems to helpe, butnot quite, as it renders markdown, but it still shows de special characters used in markdown (e.g. the ** to get bold letters)
For bash it works, as long as bash command is the only content of tab.
Once you add text before or after command  it breaks.

Comment: Share a codebase so we can have a look. Difficult to get an idea without having the whole picture.

Answer (score 1):

I also had trouble with those. We started from what was the current hugo/docsy pair. We weren't able to make the tabs from hugo/docsy set work so I took the tab/tabpane set from Kubernetes' docs implementation. It works well enough to show other html. markdown, and other shortcodes on the tab panels.

Hugo and it's themes are not a "matched" system. Themes should only control a site's look and feel, but someone foolishly decided to stuff functionality into them, as well. Feel free to explore shortcodes from other themes until you hit the one that works.

Hugo and the themes are a meatball way to generate html. If you need to write real docs, IMHO, you're better off finding a real html site generation tool. Hugo is an awkward tool that's designed for bloggers, despite what Hugo supporter will say. Look at how much time you're wasting trying to make it perform its basic functions.

Hugo is blindlingly fast at generating websites, but that's all it has going for it.

Comment: Yup, you're right. I ended up using html  for collapsible tree and that's it.
Its a shame that whats on Docsy documentation doesn't work.
And I know I was using it correctly, because other shortcodes, e.g. warning/info:

{{% alert title="INFO" color="info" %}}
{{% /alert %}}

Work perfectly fine.
I'll look into K8s docs as you said. Any link you could share will be welcomed!
ty!

Comment: That may work in a few weeks. Docsy and Hugo teams don't coordinate. Their tab/tabs shortcodes did not work for several weeks when we migrated from mkdocs and I spent days looking for why or for a set that would work. Eventually, a few weeks later, what was in the repo started working.

There are too many features required to support decent documentation. The hugo-docsy set is okay, but isn't up to the task. Authoring tools that understand what a documentation project is are much superior. That's almost entirely because the devs code what their Tech Writer SMEs asked for, not wild guesses.